# Deploy Django API + React app on Heroku

Tags: django, reactjs, docker, heroku, react-redux

I'm developing an web application with React in the front-end and Django API REST in the back-end (mostly because in the future we're gonna create a mobile app). My question is, what is the best way to deploy this web app on heroku? Using two distincts heroku's app (one for React and one for Django), or to use Docker to deploy both app's in one single heroku app? (I've read a little about Docker, but i'm not sure how I would deploy it on heroku)

Thanks and sorry for the English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way is deploying to one app by bundling all your front-end with [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/docs/) for example. If you are doing server side rendering probably its better to go for two separate apps.

[This tutorial](http://owaislone.org/blog/webpack-plus-reactjs-and-django/) talks about preparing your webpack configuration and [this repo](https://github.com/SamSamskies/django-webpack-heroku-example) shows how to deploy webpack-django heroku app